# Functions of multiple-float dataValues in Cypher

Tags: syntax, neo4j, cypher

In Cypher (to which I’m new) I have two sets of variables with instances hereafter labelled x, z, each storing two numbers, so that if there are n values of x then

```
SUM(toFloat(x.dataValue))
```

sums all 2n floats stored in the xs. To get more algebraic if the floats stored in a given x are denoted x1, x2 while those stored in a given z are denoted in z1, z2, SUM computes (if you'll pardon the LaTeX)

```
\sum_{x}(x_1+x_2).
```

In my problem context for each z a different list of xs is considered, and the SUM above would run its variable x over that z-specific list. However, I want to return a more complicated function; I want to compute

```
\sum_{x} F(x_1, x_2, z_1, z_2)
```

for some function F. What syntax can I use for this? For example, can I unpack each

```
x.dataValue
```

with something like

```
x.dataValue.Item1
```

etc. and similarly with

```
z.dataValue,
```

and then write something like

```
SUM(toFloat(F(x.dataValue.Item1, x.dataValue.Item2, z.dataValue.Item1,
z.dataValue.Item2)))?
```

Comment: @BrunoPeres Thanks for the yellow-to-grey background conversion; I couldn't work out how to create grey environments.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic? Anyway, select the block of code and 'CTRL + k` (or `command + k` if you are working in a macOS) to format as code.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. If I could have used grey environments I would have. I don't know whether Ctrl+K will work in Windows (which is what i'm using), but I'll try it next time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understood your problem completely, but I believe you can use the [reduce()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function as below:

```
WITH {dataValue : [1,2,3] } AS x, {dataValue:[10,20,30]} as y

WITH y, reduce (total = 0, item in x.dataValue | item + total) AS total_x
WITH reduce(total = total_x, item in y.dataValue | item + total) as total_sum
RETURN total_sum
```

The output will be:

```
╒═══════════╕
│"total_sum"│
╞═══════════╡
│66         │
└───────────┘
```

Comment: That's fine if I want to sum x_1+x_2+x_3+y_1+y_2+y_3, but I'm looking for something more complicated such as (x1-y1)^2/(x2^2+y2^2). I'm not sure how if at all you can do something like that with reduce().